# Implementing LISTEN command of postgres in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-boot, event-handling

I have created a trigger on a table and using pg_notify to send the event to a channel status_change. Can I implement a listener in spring boot that listens to each event whenever this trigger is activated.

I tried EventListener but that doesn't work

```
`@EventListener(condition = "#event.channel == 'status_change'")
    @Transactional
    public void handleMaintenanceUpdate(PGNotification event) {
        System.out.println("REceived Notification");
    }`
```

Comment: I don't think you can, but I'll wait and see if I'm corrected.

Answer (score 1):

This can't be done with Spring annotations because LISTEN/NOTIFY function is not available generally on every database. It is only available on PostgreSQL.

The logic need to be implemented in plain Java and JDBC as part of Spring Boot. The PostgreSQL driver provides a PGConnection interface with a method getNotifications() for reading of notifications. Sample code snippets:

First get the PGConnection and exceute LISTEN:

```
import java.sql.*;
import org.postgresql.*;
    Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
    String url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/test";
    Connection sqlConn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,"test","");
    PGConnection pgConn = sqlConn.unwrap(org.postgresql.PGConnection.class);
    Statement stmt = pgConn.createStatement();
    stmt.execute("LISTEN status_change");
    stmt.close();
```

Then get notifications and wait:

```
while (true) {
    PGNotification notifications[] = pgConn.getNotifications();
    if (notifications != null) {
        for (PGNotification notification : notifications) {
            System.out.println("Got notification: " + notification.getName());
        }
    }
    // wait a while before checking again for new  notifications
    Thread.sleep(500);
}
```

Code snippets based on https://access.crunchydata.com/documentation/pgjdbc/42.1.0/listennotify.html

Comment: Interesting. PostgreSQL surprises me again.